# <link rel="import"> устарел?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Использую Chrome Canary (которая будущая версия Chrome, которая опережает на 4 месяца stable)

Пытаюсь использовать там `<link rel="import" href="test.html">` и получаю `Warning`:

> [Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.

Но я не понимаю, чем они его предлагают заменить. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: Всмысле `чем они его предлагают заменить`, этот [`html import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) только [в chrome ведь поддерживался](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) (и следовательно вероятно его не стоило использовать в production)?

Comment: В 2017 году объявили что HTML Imports будет удалена. Фича была экспериментальной, другие браузерные компании отказались ее поддержать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### как импортировать `html` из другого `html`

всё очень просто - достаточно использовать `<!--#include virtual="URL" -->`
данная технология называется SSI

вот небольшой пример

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>SSI</title>
  </head>
 <body> 
  <!--#include virtual="/inc/header.html"-->
  <p>...</p>
  <!--#include file="../inc/footer.html"-->    
 </body>
</html>
```

ведь удобно, не правда ли, когда можно разбить один большой `html` файл на части - например заголовок, тело, подвал и загружать их из отдельных файлов. круто же!

http://htmlbook.ru/webserver/ssi
http://htmlbook.ru/webserver/ssi/direktivy-ssi
http://htmlbook.ru/metki/ssi

**ШУТКА!**

хотяя странно, ведь `css`, `html` и `js` должны быть заняты каждый своим делом - говорили они. и в подтверждении своих слов в дополнении к `@import` они ввели `link rel="import"` и `import {} from ""`/`import('').then()`. был даже написан фреймворк `Polymer` - один из вдохновителей `VueJS`.

### КАК ЖЕ БЫТЬ НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/h-JwMiPUnuU/sl79aLoLBQAJ

> There are other alternative polyfills for each, like AshleyScirra’s [HTML Imports polyfill](https://github.com/AshleyScirra/html-imports-polyfill).

https://github.com/AshleyScirra/html-imports-polyfill

> The script adds three global functions. Note the polyfill makes no effort to read existing `<link rel="import">` tags; you must use the `addImport` method instead.
>
> `addImport(url, async, progressObject)`

Answer (score 1):

В версии 80.0 я получаю следующее сообщение:

```
[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020.
Please use ES modules instead. 
See 
<ссылка заменена на работающую> https://chromestatus.com/feature/5144752345317376
and 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade
for more details.
```

Как видно, удаление функционала перенесли как минимум один раз и, учитывая текущую дату, перенесут ещё. Это слишком удобная функция, чтобы от неё отказываться, я полагаю.

**upd:**
Я нашёл метод, который вряд ли будет объявлен устаревшим в обозримом будущем, поскольку используется баннерными сетями: айфрейм.

```
<iframe id="myhtml" src="path/to/file.html" hidden=true></iframe>
```

и доступ к данным, а затем вставка на страницу:

```
var res = document.getElementById('myhtml').contentWindow.document
document.innerHTML += res
```

Метод очень груб, но абсолютно надёжен. 
Возможно это поможет, если кто-то наткнётся на этот вопрос в будущем.